# alternatives to SGE

Tags: gridengine

Once upon at time there was the free SGE from Sun. tricky to install and configure, but functional and free.

Now we've got:

1. open source packages on Ubuntu that don't quite work out of the box (details on request).
2. the actual source behind them, with a build process that depends on the c-shell and other obsolescences, available from two competing locations.
3. a commercial packaging from Oracle
4. a commercial package from Univa

What I am really wishing for is something with the basic capabilities of this that is simple to install and maintain. Heck, I'd take a front-end to hadoop that just queues and distributes simple shell-script-defined jobs.

Comment: LSF?  http://www.platform.com/workload-management/high-performance-computing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was [Torque](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=torque) one of the non-working packages from point 1? If not, that's where I'd start. If so, I don't recall it being that hard to set up a few years back, but opinions may vary. More advanced queuing, resource reservations, etc. would require something like Cluster Resources' [Maui](http://www.clusterresources.com/products/maui-cluster-scheduler.php) scheduler on the server side. The client side can still use Torque for job submission and such.

Comment: No. Torque is a fine and I didn't know about it until about an hour ago. Pity that natty includes an apparently busted pbs_sched, forcing me to fight with maui.